# How to create a friend function for template base class with constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, friend-function, class-template

I want to create a overloaded `operator<<` for a template base class, that calls the `toString` function for the child class. The issue is that the `toString` function of the child class is `constexpr`, which mean I cannot make it a virtual function of the base class. Here is what I want to do:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
  Base(const T& t) : m_val(t) {}
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Base& base);
protected:
  const T m_val;
};

class Child1 : public Base<SomeLiteralType1> {
public:
  using Base::Base;
  constexpr const char* toString() {
    const char* LUT[] = {"aa", "bb"};
    return LUT[m_val];  // <-- assume T can be converted to int
  }
};

class Child2 : public Base<SomeLiteralType2> {
...
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Base& base) {
  // cannot access toString() since it is not defined in Base
  // maybe using dynamic_cast?
}

int main() {
  Child1 c1 = {...};
  Child2 c2 = {...};
  // I want to be able to use << directly:
  std::cout<<c1<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<c2<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `toString` is a `public` static member function, you have access to it anywhere you want with `Chlid::ToString` but `m_val` is a member variable. Which mean that your example doesn't compile.

Comment: @Stiven my fault. only the `LUT` inside the `toString` is meant to be `static const`. I have fixed it.

Comment: Which C++ standard do you use? If you are using C++20 you can make a virtual constexpr member function

Comment: @Stiven c++17 at most

Comment: In your example, you can't instantiate a `constexpr` child. So why bother to put `toString` in `constexpr`. An other thing, you used private inheritance, is this on purpose or your forgot to add the `public` keyword? If it's on purpose you will not be able to use polymorphism because you can't cast a `Child&` to a `Base&`

Comment: @Stiven yes I forgot to put the public keyword for inheritance. The reason to use `constrexpr toString()` is that `Child1` object is typically used as a `constexpr` object.

Comment: Why not directly make an operator<< for Child1 instead of Base ? Since it seems that `toString` will only be defined for `Chlid1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to get access to the derived class:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Derived>
class Base {
  ...

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base& base) {
    return os << static_cast<const Derived&>(base).toString();
  }

  ...
};

class Child1 : public Base<int, Child1> {
  ...
};
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Ge7b3r9na)

Answer (score 0):

Since c++20, virtual function can be `constexpr`, so you can have:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
  constexpr Base(const T& t) : m_val(t) {}
  virtual const char* toString() = 0;
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Base& base)
  {
    return os << base.toString();
  }
protected:
  const T m_val;
};
class Child1 : public Base<SomeLiteralType1> {
public:
  using Base::Base;
  constexpr const char* toString() override {
    const char* LUT[] = {"aa", "bb"};
    return LUT[m_val];  // <-- assume T can be converted to int
  }
};
```

In previous version, as you don't need `constexpr` in the base class anyway, you might have a virtual function and the constexpr function:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
  constexpr Base(const T& t) : m_val(t) {}
  virtual const char* virtualToString() = 0;
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Base& base)
  {
    return os << base.virtualToString();
  }
protected:
  const T m_val;
};
class Child1 : public Base<SomeLiteralType1> {
public:
  using Base::Base;
  constexpr const char* toString() {
    const char* LUT[] = {"aa", "bb"};
    return LUT[m_val];  // <-- assume T can be converted to int
  }
  const char* virtualToString() override {
    return toString();
  }
};
```